# Efficient Indexes for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Given the following sample MongoDB document:

```
{
      _id: someval,
      metadata: {
           host: some-host.com,
           path: /some/path.html,
           date: ISODate("2000-10-10T00:00:00Z")
      }
}
```

What is the most optimized way to index the data if the following two queries will be repeatedly performed?

```
db.stats.daily.find(
     {
         'metadata.date': { '$gte': dt1, '$lte': dt2 },
         'metadata.host': 'site-1'},
     { 'metadata.date': 1, 'hourly': 1 } },
     sort=[('metadata.date', 1)])

db.stats.daily.find(
     {
         'metadata.date': { '$gte': dt1, '$lte': dt2 },
         'metadata.host': 'site-1',
         'metadata.path': '/index.html'},
     { 'metadata.date': 1, 'hourly': 1 } },
     sort=[('metadata.date', 1)])
```